# xslt choose node based on values order

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml.

```
<root>
    <!-- E, F, G, H-->
    <node1>E</node1>
    <!-- J, K, M ,L-->
    <node2>J</node2>
</root>
```

Node 1 can have E,F,G,H values and node 2 can have J,K,M,L.

I would like to choose a single node base on its value.

I need to choose the values based on the following order E,J,F,K,G,M,H,L.

I know that I can do this with a choose.

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- sequence, E,J,F,K,G,M,H,L-->
        <xsl:variable name="myNode" select="root/node1 || root/node2"/>
        <output>        
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($myNode, 'E')">
                    <xsl:text>E</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($myNode, 'J')">
                    <xsl:text>J</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($myNode, 'F')">
                    <xsl:text>F</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($myNode, 'K')">
                    <xsl:text>K</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($myNode, 'G')">
                    <xsl:text>G</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($myNode, 'M')">
                    <xsl:text>M</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($myNode, 'H')">
                    <xsl:text>H</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains($myNode, 'L')">
                    <xsl:text>L</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
```

but is there an easier (less code) way to achieve this? Maybe a regular expression? I would like to have this in xslt 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just sort the nodes and take the value of the first node in the sorted sequence?

Comment: If the value is always one of those single letters, why the `contains` call, why no `$myNode = 'E'` comparison?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but if I sort the order would be alphabetical instead of E,J,F,K,G,M,H,L?

Comment: Not if you sort by `index-of`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the single-letter values in your question are for example purposes only (otherwise this could be even simpler). Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <node1>F</node1>
    <node2>J</node2>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="order" select="('E','J','F','K','G','M','H','L')" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="sorted">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="node1 | node2">
          <xsl:sort select="index-of($order, .)"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort> 
    </xsl:variable> 
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="$sorted/*[1]"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>J</output>
```

Comment: Another option would be to sort on `select="translate(., 'EJFKGMHL', 'abcdefgh')"`

Comment: @MichaelKay That would work only if the real values are the single-letter values used in the given example - which I doubt is the case.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question is simple: No, built-in XSLT does not support to write this in a simpler way, AFAIK.

Perhaps you should consider to move the logic of the complicated computation out of the XSL by using a user-defined function such as `takeOrderedString(node1, node2)` that you'll have to implement yourself.

```
<xsl:value-of select="takeOrderedString(root/node1,root/node2)" />
```

Comment: You are seriously underestimating what can be done in XSLT - especially with 2.0+

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the comment. I guess ist is feasible for simple cases. I don't know the challenges it might bear to maintain such a complex logic written in XSLT. Perhaps there exists simpler ways as in the example provided in the question (which IMHO is short and best regarding readability). Also I'm not quite sure of the impact on the performance when dealing w/ such advanced logic.